# Problem with Crunch occurring after some time FtpWebRequest in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

i have this Code From My Class

The code is working fine, but the memory is increasing, which is causing Crunch to close the program for itself

I tried all the methods and did not find a solution to this problem

```
Imports System.Net
Imports System.IO
Public Class class1

    Private host As String
    Private password As String
    Private username As String
    Dim x As New List(Of String)

    Public Sub New(host As String, username As String, password As String)
        Me.host = host
        Me.username = username
        Me.password = password
    End Sub

    Friend Sub start()

        Try
            Dim request As FtpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create("ftp://" + Me.host)
            request.Timeout = 4000
            request.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(Me.username, Me.password)
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectory
            '-----------------------------------
            Try
                '-----------------------------------
                Dim listResponse As FtpWebResponse = request.GetResponse()
               ' listResponse = request.GetResponse()
                Dim reader As StreamReader = New System.IO.StreamReader(listResponse.GetResponseStream())
                Dim Filedata As String = reader.ReadToEnd
                '-----------------------------------
                x.Add(Filedata)
                '-----------------------------------
                File.WriteAllLines(IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() & "\logs.txt", x)
                '-----------------------------------
                Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)
                listResponse.Close()
                listResponse.Dispose()
                request.Abort()
            Catch ex As WebException
                request.Abort()
                Exit Sub
            End Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            Exit Sub
        End Try
        Exit Sub
    End Sub
End Class
```

i Call this class from the main app

This method call

And use threading

```
Dim x As New testing(host, username, password)
x.start()
```

can anyone help me do this i am using Vb.net

Comment: `StreamReader` is disposable, declare it in a `Using` statement (you should do the same with the `FtpWebResponse`). Why do you have two `request.GetResponse()`, remove the second and cast to `FtpWebResponse` the first. You can remove `Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)` and  `request.Abort()` is a real *no*. You don't need threads, you can use the `async` version of the FtpWebRequest methods and throttle some Tasks (or `await Task.WhenAll()`, depending on the context of your operations).

Comment: you can edit code and give me new code ?